# how to use if statement for number range

Tags: c#

I have a `TextBox` where users write numbers 1-12 to represent the month. My current code is below:

```
int month;
month = int.Parse(textbox.Text);
if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This will perform the expected action if the user's entry was valid (1-12) but it doesn't prevent them from entering an invalid input in the first place. Is there a way to constrain the textbox to force users to enter a number 1-12 in the first place?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong. Clarify what you mean by "write over 12" please.

Comment: @JunLe 俊乐  what issue you're facing. your code is correct

Comment: Why do you think this would prevent you from putting anything else into `textbox.Text`?

Comment: If you want to limit user input between numeric values, .NET has a easy to use control call a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Edited my answer, if you want people only to be able to enter numbers between  1-12 it works perfectly.

Comment: i making a textbox which let people write down 01 to 12 for monthly

Comment: write down 01 to 12 oni

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066205/how-to-constrain-a-textbox

Comment: I edited to include details from the comments and to be more explicit about what you're looking to achieve, please let me know if the edit's OK.

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing would be to do something like this:

```
// You might want to consider using int.TryParse here instead because if
// the user accidentally wrote something other than an int this'll throw
// an exception
int month = int.Parse(textbox.Text);
if (month >= 1 && month <= 12)
{
    //dostuff
}
else {
  // Show dialog box prompting the user to enter 1 - 12
}
```

The better solution would be to use one of the validation mechanisms in place in your UI library. You didn't tag which one you were using, but you can see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066205/how-to-constrain-a-textbox) for a WPF example of how to constrain a textbox.

You might also consider just using a drop-down menu instead if you're just asking users to select between a small number of options. (Radio buttons are an option too, but they only make sense if you have a very small number of choices, 3 - 4 at most is my general rule of thumb, so I don't think that they'd be a good choice here).